# Replication operator for ignoring bit

Tags: verilog

Is it is possible to selectively map bits from an output of a module?  For example:

```
module A (
   input  wire [4:0] X,
   output wire [4:0] Y
)
endmodule

module B (
..
)
(
wire  [2:0] w;
wire  [2:0] v;
A I1 (
   .X ({{2{1'b1}},w}),
   .Y (??????,v)
);

endmodule
```

Is there any syntax that would allow me to pick desired bits for wire `v` without having to create an additional wire and using `assign` statements?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make this connection:

```
.Y (v)
```

but you'll likely get compile warnings from your simulator.

To avoid the warnings, you could create a wire, but there is no need for an assign:

```
module A (
    input  wire [4:0] X,
    output wire [4:0] Y
);
endmodule

module B;
wire  [2:0] w;
wire  [2:0] v;
wire  [1:0] noconn;
A I1 (
    .X ({{2{1'b1}},w}),
    .Y ({noconn, v})
);
endmodule
```